# Rails nested association. in render :json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Existing questions have gotten me 90% of the way to what I want, but there's a hitch.

I have a `CheckIns` model, and a `Person` model. `CheckIns` belong to `People`.

In my controller, I have this code:

```
data = CheckIn.all
render json: { data: data }
```

For each `CheckIn`, I'd like to nest the associated `Person` in it. Past StackOverflow questions suggest I do this:

```
data = CheckIn.all
render json: data.to_json include: :person
```

But, this makes it difficult to nest my data inside of a wrapper JSON object, like I originally did, because `to_json` creates a string, not a `Hash`.

I want the wrapper JSON object so that I can follow a standardized JSON output, where `data` is always in a `data:` field, and other metadata can be attached to the response.

How can I get the effect of the `include:` flag for `to_json`, while also keeping the wrapper object? In particular, this is not a valid answer for me, since it's really ugly:

```
data = CheckIn.all
render json: { data: JSON.parse data.to_json(include: :person) }
```

Thanks! Hope there's an idiomatic way to do this in Rails.

Comment: I'd highly suggest the use of Jbuilder or RABL to format your JSON as opposed to  .to_json. Both these gems offer much more explicit DSL's to format your JSON.

Comment: jbuilder is your friend...

Comment: Yeah, I knew about JBuilder already, but I'm specifically wondering if I could do this stuff a) without `to_json`, and b) without introducing views into my project. If it's not doable, that's fine, but it was nice to have my response generation being so explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active Records support eager loading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

loading checkins associated with user:

```
@users = User.all.includes(:checkins)
```

will be querying:

```
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
Checkin Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "checkins".* FROM "checkins"  WHERE "checkins"."user_id" IN (1)
```

but this wont let you render your nested objects, what you are looking for is something to Decorate your data

take a look at https://github.com/nesquena/rabl or github.com/rails/jbuilder

You will be able to provide decorator with templates and data object to render

Comment: I wanted to see if I could avoid using templating in this scenario, but it appears not. Ah well, thanks regardless!